# How does terminal points work for edges in mxGraph? Need edges to connect at left-side-mid-height of a vertex

Tags: mxgraph

```
edge = graph.insertEdge(parent,
                                null,
                                '',
                                vertex1,
                                vertex2);

var destX = vertex2.geometry.x;
var destY = vertex2.geometry.y;
var destHeight = vertex2.geometry.height;
var sourceX = vertex2.geometry.x;
var sourceY = vertex2.geometry.y;
var sourceHeight = vertex2.geometry.height;
edge.geometry.setTerminalPoint(new 
                         mxPoint(sourceX,sourceY+(sourceHeight/2)),true);
edge.geometry.setTerminalPoint(new 
                    mxPoint(destX,destY+(destHeight/2)),false);
edge.geometry.relative = true;
```

This is creating the default edge.Please assume that the vertex is inserted.

Comment: did u get your answer? on how to connect to specific connection point on the target?

Answer (score 0):

The terminal points are only required if an edge is unconnected, and are stored in the sourcePoint> and targetPoint variables, respectively.

https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/model/mxGeometry-js.html#mxGeometry